# Windows Forms - PNG with transparency as background

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I'm working on a small personal project and I need to create a non-rectanguar window (a circle to be more precise - though that might change) that has a drop shadow. I have the round window by changing the Region property if the form with a png set as background.

The thing is the window is alised and the transparency of the PNG is not working. So the question is how do I get a a antialised window and the transparency of the background image OR the antialised circular window and a way to add the drop shadow effect to the window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a [Layered Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) using P/Invoke.

[Here](http://devblog.antongochev.net/2008/07/30/create-custom-ui-appearance-for-winforms-layered-form-part-5/) is a .Net example.